# Proving ${l/2}*b_n<a_n<(3l/2)*b_n$ when $a_n/b_n \rightarrow l$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Suppose $<a_n>$ and $<b_n>$ are sequences with $a_n$, $b_n$ $>0$ for all $n$, and there is a real number $l>0$ such that $a_n/b_n \rightarrow l$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then show:
There exists a number $N>0$ such that ${l/2}*b_n<a_n<(3l/2)*b_n$ for all $n>N$.

Since we know that $a_n/b_n \rightarrow l$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then for $\varepsilon>0$ $\exists N\in R$,  $\forall n>N$ s.t. $|a_n/b_n -l|<\varepsilon$

Since $b_n$ is positive, then:
$|a_n -l*b_n|<\varepsilon*b_n$

Now, by considering left hand side:
$|a_n -l*b_n| = |a_n - 3/2l*b_n + 1/2l*b_n| \leq |a_n - 3/2 l*b_n| + |1/2l*b_n|$ by using triangular inequality.

From here I do not know what to do. Perhaps I did not even need to do what I just wrote but those were my thoughts.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Hint: Choose $\epsilon=\frac{l}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, we can assume $l=1$.

take $$\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}.$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1 \implies$$

$\exists N\geq0 : \forall n>N $

$$1-\epsilon<\frac{a_n}{b_n}<1+\epsilon\implies$$

$$(\forall n>N)\;\;\frac{1}{2}b_n<a_n<\frac{3}{2}b_n.$$

if $l\neq1$ replace $b_n$ by $lb_n$

Comment: five minutes ago and after

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you please explain why we can assume that $l = 1$ without loss of generality?

Comment: @Blondie If $l\neq 1$ then $\frac{a_n}{lb_n}$ goes to one.

Comment: But would not be $lb_n$ another sequence? So, for example if $b_n$ was to converge to $x$ then $lb_n$ would converge to $lx$ and so that would be a different sequence with a different limit

Comment: @Blondie If $l\neq1$, you apply the case $l=1$ to $a_n$ and $cn=l b_n$.